# Array vacio en consulta SQLITE

Tags: android-studio, android-sqlite, android-recyclerview

estoy tratando de mostrar una consulta SQlite en un recyclerview pero al tratar de correrla la aplicación se cierra y me indica que el Array esta vacío, alguien  me podría dar una mano para saber en que punto podría estar fallando.

Error Log

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
at com.example.formsaide.Adaptadores.AdaptadorRegistros.getItemCount(AdaptadorRegistros.java:85)

Este es el código de la clase Consulta del activity

```
public class Consulta extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerViewRegistros; //referencia al recyclerView creado

    ArrayList<Items> listaItems; //lista de tipo Items para guardar los datos consultados
    ConexionSQLiteHelper conn; //conexion a la base de datos

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_consulta);

        conn = new ConexionSQLiteHelper(getApplicationContext(), "bd_datos", null, 1);

        //instancia y casteo al recyclerView creado
        recyclerViewRegistros = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        // se indica al recycler como se cargaran los datos, por defecto se deja this para que lo tome vertical
        recyclerViewRegistros.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        //metodo encargado de generar la consulta a la base de datos
        consultaRegistros();

        //instancia del array listaItems
        listaItems = new ArrayList<>();

        //ListAdapter adaptador = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listaItems);

        //referecia a AdaptadorRegistros
        AdaptadorRegistros adapter = new AdaptadorRegistros(listaItems);
        recyclerViewRegistros.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void consultaRegistros() {
        //se abre la base en modo lectura
        SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getReadableDatabase();
        //se instancia el objeto Items para llear la información
        Items items = null;

        // se realiza la referencia Cursor para consulta a la tabla datos

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + Utilidades.TABLA_DATOS, null);
        //se creea una lista para la clase Items
        listaItems = new ArrayList<Items>();

        // se recorre con un While el resultado almacenado en cursor y luego se almacena en la instancia del  objeto Items
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            items = new Items(); //instancia del objeto Items, al final se agrega a la listaItems

            items.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            items.setFecha(cursor.getString(1));
            items.setcodigo(cursor.getString(2));
            items.setObservaciones(cursor.getString(45));

            items.setR1_ma(cursor.getString(5));
            items.setR1_pc(cursor.getString(6));
            items.setR1_tt(cursor.getString(7));
            items.setR1_tr(cursor.getString(8));
            items.setR1_td(cursor.getString(9));
            items.setR1_tc(cursor.getString(10));
            items.setR1_ca(cursor.getString(11));
            items.setR1_fito(cursor.getString(12));
            items.setR1_sc(cursor.getString(13));
            items.setR1_cap(cursor.getString(14));

            items.setR2_ma(cursor.getString(15));
            items.setR2_pc(cursor.getString(16));
            items.setR2_tt(cursor.getString(17));
            items.setR2_tr(cursor.getString(18));
            items.setR2_td(cursor.getString(19));
            items.setR2_tc(cursor.getString(20));
            items.setR2_ca(cursor.getString(21));
            items.setR2_fito(cursor.getString(22));
            items.setR2_sc(cursor.getString(23));
            items.setR2_cap(cursor.getString(24));

            items.setR3_ma(cursor.getString(25));
            items.setR3_pc(cursor.getString(26));
            items.setR3_tt(cursor.getString(27));
            items.setR3_tr(cursor.getString(28));
            items.setR3_td(cursor.getString(29));
            items.setR3_tc(cursor.getString(30));
            items.setR3_ca(cursor.getString(31));
            items.setR3_fito(cursor.getString(32));
            items.setR3_sc(cursor.getString(33));
            items.setR3_cap(cursor.getString(34));

            items.setR4_ma(cursor.getString(35));
            items.setR4_pc(cursor.getString(36));
            items.setR4_tt(cursor.getString(37));
            items.setR4_tr(cursor.getString(38));
            items.setR4_td(cursor.getString(39));
            items.setR4_tc(cursor.getString(40));
            items.setR4_ca(cursor.getString(41));
            items.setR4_fito(cursor.getString(42));
            items.setR4_sc(cursor.getString(43));
            items.setR4_cap(cursor.getString(44));

            listaItems.add(items);
        }
    }
```

Este es el código de mi adaptador para el RecyclerView

```
public class AdaptadorRegistros extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorRegistros.ViewHolderREgistros> {
    //ArrayList<String> listaItems;
    ArrayList<Items> listaItems;

    public AdaptadorRegistros(ArrayList<Items> listaItems) {
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolderREgistros onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //Se infla el layout auxiliar
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lregistros,null,false);
        //Se retorna una instancia nueva de ViewHolderREgistros
        return new ViewHolderREgistros(view);
    }

    @Override
    //Comunica a ViewHolderREgistros y el adaptador
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolderREgistros holder, int position) {
        //con holder se crea un método que asigna el Array que trae los datos

        holder.fecha.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getFecha());
        holder.codigo.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getcodigo());
        holder.ma1.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getR1_ma());
        holder.pc1.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getR1_pc());
        holder.tt1.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getR1_tt());
        holder.tr1.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getR1_tr());
        holder.td1.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getR1_td());
        holder.tc1.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getR1_tc());
        holder.ca1.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getR1_ca());
        holder.fito1.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getR1_fito());
        holder.sc1.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getR1_sc());
        holder.cap1.setText(listaItems.get(position).getR1_cap());
        holder.ma2.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getR2_ma());
        holder.pc2.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getR2_pc());
        holder.tt2.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getR2_tt());
        holder.tr2.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getR2_tr());
        holder.td2.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getR2_td());
        holder.tc2.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getR2_tc());
        holder.ca2.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getR2_ca());
        holder.fito2.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getR2_fito());
        holder.sc2.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getR2_sc());
        holder.cap2.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getR2_cap());
        holder.ma3.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getR3_ma());
        holder.pc3.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getR3_pc());
        holder.tt3.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getR3_tt());
        holder.tr3.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getR3_tr());
        holder.td3.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getR3_td());
        holder.tc3.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getR3_tc());
        holder.ca3.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getR3_ca());
        holder.fito3.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getR3_fito());
        holder.sc3.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getR3_sc());
        holder.cap3.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getR3_cap());
        holder.ma4.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getR4_ma());
        holder.pc4.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getR4_pc());
        holder.tt4.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getR4_tt());
        holder.tr4.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getR4_tr());
        holder.td4.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getR4_td());
        holder.tc4.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getR4_tc());
        holder.ca4.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getR4_ca());
        holder.fito4.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getR4_fito());
        holder.sc4.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getR4_sc());
        holder.cap4.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getR4_cap());
        holder.obser.setText((CharSequence) listaItems.get(position).getObservaciones());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
            return listaItems.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolderREgistros extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView codigo,fecha,
                ma1,pc1,tt1,tr1,td1,tc1,ca1,fito1,sc1,cap1,
                ma2,pc2,tt2,tr2,td2,tc2,ca2,fito2,sc2,cap2,
                ma3,pc3,tt3,tr3,td3,tc3,ca3,fito3,sc3,cap3,
                ma4,pc4,tt4,tr4,td4,tc4,ca4,fito4,sc4,cap4,obser;
        public ViewHolderREgistros(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            codigo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCodigo);
            fecha = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFecha);
            ma1 =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvMa1);
            pc1 =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPC1);
            tt1 =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTT1);
            tr1 =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTR1);
            td1 =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTD1);
            tc1 =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTC1);
            ca1 =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCA1);
            fito1 =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFito1);
            sc1 =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSC1);
            cap1 =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCAP1);
            ma2 =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvMa2);
            pc2 =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPC2);
            tt2 =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTT2);
            tr2 =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTR2);
            td2 =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTD2);
            tc2 =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTC2);
            ca2 =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCA2);
            fito2 =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFito2);
            sc2 =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSC2);
            cap2 =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCAP2);
            ma3 =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvMa3);
            pc3 =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPC3);
            tt3 =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTT3);
            tr3 =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTR3);
            td3 =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTD3);
            tc3 =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTC3);
            ca3 =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCA3);
            fito3 =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFito3);
            sc3 =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSC3);
            cap3 =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCAP3);
            ma4 =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvMa4);
            pc4 =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPC4);
            tt4 =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTT4);
            tr4 =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTR4);
            td4 =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTD4);
            tc4 =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTC4);
            ca4 =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCA4);
            fito4 =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFito4);
            sc4 =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSC4);
            cap4 =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCAP4);
            obser =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvObser);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que en el constructor de tu Adapter no estas inicializando el `ArrayList` por esta razón obtienes el error "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference":

```
 public AdaptadorRegistros(ArrayList<Items> listaItems) {
    }
```

debes realizarlo de esta forma

```
 public AdaptadorRegistros(ArrayList<Items> listaItems) {
      this.listaItems = listaItems;
    }
```

de esta forma al llamar el método `getItemCount()` de tu Adapter ya podrá llamar el método `size()` a partir del `ArrayList` recibido:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
        return listaItems.size();
}
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias, me has ayudado mucho llevaba dos días tratando de saber que era, enserio muchas gracias, saludos desde Colombia.